# Changing value of variables in child components and textfields react

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm trying to create components a (parent, child and input) and pass variables from the parent component to child and input components, allow for the variables to change within the child components and access the mutated variable in the parent component. With the below code, the text doesn't update when typing in the input field, and my `setValue` function isn't called in the parent component. Also, as you can see in my code below, the function `setValue` is there to handle all of the possible variable changes, but I'm not sure how to implement that. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function CreateAccount() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const setValue = (newValue, valueType) => {
    if (valueType === 'email') setEmail(newValue);
    else if (valueType === 'password') setPassword(newValue);
    else setConfirmPassword(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        email={email}
        password={password}
        confirmPassword={confirmPassword}
        viewType='createClientAccount'
        onChangeState={setValue}
      />
      <hr/>
      <div>Email is:{email}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Form({ email, password, confirmPassword, viewType, onChangeState }) {
  if (viewType === 'createClientAccount') {
    return (
      <div className='box-shadow'>
        <h2>Create Client Account</h2>

        <TextInputField
          label={'Email'}
          value={email}
          onChangeState={onChangeState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function TextInputField({ label, value, onChangeState }) {
  function onChange() {
    onChangeState(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className='inputFieldWrapper'>
      <p>{label}</p>
      <input name='email' value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<CreateAccount />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code you provided:

1. your function `onChange()` in the `TextInputField` is not passing the change value to `onChangeState()`.  It is only passing the value of the `value` prop, which is the original value being passed in from the parent.
2. the "onChange handler" for the [`<input> onChange prop`](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input#props) is passed an Event object, from which you would extract the newly typed value.
3. the `setValue()` function you are passing down requires 2 parameters (type and value).
4. the `label` props (which appears to be a rename of `type` expected by `setValue()` was given the value of `"Email"` but the code in `setValue()` was checking for the value of `"email"` (lower-case).

This snippet I think shows a bit of what you were trying to accomplish?

```js
const { useState } = React;

function CreateAccount() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const setValue = (newValue, valueType) => {
    if (valueType === 'email') setEmail(newValue);
    else if (valueType === 'password') setPassword(newValue);
    else setConfirmPassword(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        email={email}
        password={password}
        confirmPassword={confirmPassword}
        viewType='createClientAccount'
        onChangeState={setValue}
      />
      <hr/>
      <div>Email is: <span style={{color: 'red'}}>{email}</span></div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Form({ email, password, confirmPassword, viewType, onChangeState }) {
  if (viewType === 'createClientAccount') {
    return (
      <div className='box-shadow'>
        <h2>Create Client Account</h2>

        <TextInputField
          label={'email'}
          value={email}
          onChangeState={onChangeState}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function TextInputField({ label, value, onChangeState }) {
  function onChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;
    onChangeState(newValue, label);
  }

  return (
    <div className='inputFieldWrapper'>
      <p>{label}</p>
      <input name={label} value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<CreateAccount />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: hmmm....not sure why it posted this as a new comment rather than an update?

Comment: [@mfusco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15007914/mfusco) if you agree with the solution here, please selected it as the chosen solution.